# Pagination not working

Tags: plugins, php, wp-query, pagination

$paged for pagination is awlays returning 1, so no matter what page i click "1" is always highlighted and it always shows the same posts. i have tried a million different combinations of things to fix and nothing works :(

```
<ul>
     <?php 



        wp_reset_query();

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
echo $paged;
        $mixtapes = new WP_Query ( array
          ( 'post_type' => 'mixtapes', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged'=>$paged ) 
        );


        while ($mixtapes->have_posts()) : $mixtapes->the_post();

          $img_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'image',true);
          $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($img_id);
          ?>

         <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="cover" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/timthumb.php?src='.str_replace("http://freshnewmixtapes.net","",$img_url).'&q=100&h=176&w=176'; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
</a>
          <h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="download">Download</a>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="play">Play</a>

         </li>

        <?php 
        endwhile;?>
       <?php ?>
</ul>

<br style="clear:both;">
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $mixtapes ) );
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) under WP_Query in Codex:

> Since Wordpress 3.0.2, you do get_query_var( 'page' ) instead of get_query_var( 'paged' ). The pagination parameter 'paged' for WP_Query() remains the same.